# VBA: Filter Rows and Copy to new Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, filter, filtering

I am new with VBA and please need some help if possible. I have 50 rows of data with 4 different car names (FIAT,SEAT,MINI,VOLVO) and I would like to copy them separately. First I would like to have 15 FIAT rows then 10 SEAT rows, then 15 MINI rows and then 10 VOLVO rows). I have already extracted the 4 unique values and tried to create a loop for these 4 values

I tried the following code

```
for i=1 to 4   car=Sheets("cars").Cells(55,i)  With Sheets("cars")
   With .Range("A2:X52")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="car"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("results").Cells(freerow, 2)
End With                                       End With
```

I would be grateful if somebody could give a hint, thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem with the current code?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to perform the transfer.

```
Sub moveCars()
    Dim i As Long, cars As Variant

    cars = Array("fiat", "seat", "mini", "volvo")

    With Worksheets("cars")
       With .Range("A2:X52")
            For i = LBound(cars) To UBound(cars)
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cars(i)
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                  Destination:=Worksheets("results").Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Next i
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Seeing as how you are moving 15, then 10, then 15, then 10 wouldn't a custom sort order be more appropriate on the 50 cells (A2:X52)?